# Implementing promise queues with native promises?

Tags: promise, q, es6-promise

I refer to you to the excellent article "[A General Theory of Reactivity](https://github.com/kriskowal/gtor)" by @kriskowal. In it, he gives the following implementation of a promises queue, using Q conventions:

```
function PromiseQueue() {
    var ends = Promise.defer();
    this.put = function (value) {
        var next = Promise.defer();
        ends.resolve({
            head: value,
            tail: next.promise
        });
        ends.resolve = next.resolve;
    };
    this.get = function () {
        var result = ends.promise.get("head");
        ends.promise = ends.promise.get("tail");
        return result;
    };
}
```

You'll see it's using Q features such as `defer` and `get`. I'm trying to wrap my ahead around how to adapt this to use native promises, but am experiencing massive brain freeze. (In the process of working on this, I also came across the fact that Chrome appears to provide a `Promise.defer` method, which AFAIK is not in the spec.)

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh wow that's cool people are actually reading gtor :D

In ES6 promises, the replacement for `.defer` is the promise constructor:

```
this.put = function (value) {
    var r;
    var p = new Promise(function(resolve){ r = resolve; });
    ends.resolve({
        head: value,
        tail: p
    });
    ends.resolve = r;
};
```

And `.get('foo')` is just syntactic sugar for `.then(function(val){ return val['foo']; })` so that translates rather directly:

```
this.get = function () {
    var result = ends.promise.then(function(v){ return v["head"]; });
    ends.promise = ends.promise.then(function(v){ return v["tail"]; });
    return result;
};
```

Similarly, since you don't have `ends` you map it with the promise constructor - you can always do:

```
var o = {};
var p = new Promise(function(res, rej){ o.res = res; o.rej = rej; });
o.promise = p;
// o is now a deferred
```

Note that Kris's queue is mainly for illustrative purposes and to explain the concept - personally I never actually got to use it for anything practical. Its use case scenario is very subtle, usually if you want to queue promises you'd just use `.then`.